# Android and Json Get Data

Tags: java, android, json, api

I'm working on my first Android Application and I'm having issue with using API and getting data using Json. This is the API [link](http://muslimsalat.com/api/)

API code  :

```
    jQuery(function($) {
     $.getJSON('http://muslimsalat.com/london/daily.json?key=API_KEY&jsoncallback=?', function (times)
     {
         $('.prayerTimesExample')
         .append('Today in '+times.title)
         .append(' Fajr: '+times.items[0].fajr)
         .append(' Dhuhr: '+times.items[0].dhuhr)
         .append(' Asr: '+times.items[0].asr)
         .append(' Maghrib: '+times.items[0].maghrib)
         .append(' Isha: '+times.items[0].isha)
         .append(' by MuslimSalat.com');
     });
});
```

So I need your help how to call this API and get the result into string an explication or example. Thanks you

Comment: I don't know what you want. What does jQuery have to do with Android and Java? Explain what you want to do.

Comment: Honestlly even me I confused, I found the API over here : http://muslimsalat.com/api/ check it please I can't understand how it works an use. This my first time with Android and API JSON

Comment: Maybe this could help to understant it : https://www.mashape.com/muslim/muslim-salat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've get the key for that api i.e. 5ad273b81ff66c6f3248604cfc728baa
call simple api .... [api call to get daily prayer](http://muslimsalat.com/daily.json?key=5ad273b81ff66c6f3248604cfc728baa)

use code to fetch value...

```
try
            {
                HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request=new HttpGet("http://muslimsalat.com/daily.json?key=5ad273b81ff66c6f3248604cfc728baa");
                HttpResponse response=client.execute(request);

                HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
                String json=EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(json);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonObject.getString("title")+"\n"+jsonObject.getString("prayer_method_name"), 0).show();

                entity.consumeContent();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.getStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString()  , 0).show();
            }
```